HotFix not detecting AddOn setups
I have created an AddOn setup for a base setup by setting the RelatedBundle action to AddOn. and also created a patch for the AddOn setup. However, only the base product is being detected in the DetectRelatedBundle action.
Why is the addon related bundle ID not being detected during HF installation?
